# Dc.js Pie Chart is running out of colours for the sections and the color methods in dc cannot be found when compiled

Tags: dc.js

I'm currently having an issue with dc.js when building a pie chart. The number of sections that the pie chart generates is fairly large as I am using the results of a mongodb query to populate the pie chart.

The problem I am having is that the pie chart appears to be running out of colours for the sections. So far I have tried to use the [dc.colorMixin method ordinalColors()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.colorMixin.html#ordinalColors__anchor) to try and improve the situation but I get an error in the browser (Chrome) that ordinalColors() is not a function even though it is part of dc.js.

So if anyone could help out with the chart colours running out or the fact that dc can't seem to use ordinalColors it would be appreciated.

Here's the charts, it's the genre chart that's causing the problems: [image: Working Chart. Less Working Chart]

Here's the code section that builds the chart:

```
var genreChart = dc.pieChart('#genre-chart');
var genreData = genreJson;
var genreCrossfilter = crossfilter(genreData);
var genreDimension = genreCrossfilter.dimension(function(data) 
{
        return data.Genre;
});
var genreGroup = genreDimension.group().reduceCount();

genreChart
    .width(500)
    .height(300)
    .dimension(genreDimension)
    .group(genreGroup)
    .label(function(d){ return d.data.key + ": " + d.data.value});
    //.ordinalColors(['red', 'green', 'blue']);
```

This is the first question I've asked here so feel free to offer feedback.

Comment: Two things are strange here. First, `ordinalColors` definitely exists, and it worked for me in a quick test. Second, I think the d3 ordinal scale normally cycles, so it shouldn't go all grey like that, it should start again at blue. You could try `genreChart.colors(d3.scale.ordinal().range(['red','green','blue']))` which should do the same thing. Or, if possible. create a fiddle demonstrating the problem.

Comment: The genreChart.colors(d3.scale.ordinal().range(['red','green','blue'])) did help in that I no longer get grey portions but now it colours two slices red and green then colours the rest of the portions blue

Comment: Um, okay, what if you give it a lot more colors?

Comment: I wound up generating an array of hex colour codes the same length as the number of pie chart slices and feeding that into .range(). It's not very elegant but it works.

Comment: Great! Generally there is no good way to deal with categorical dimensions greater than about 10 items, since human eyes can't distinguish that many colors. So that's about the best you can do.